# Adding a keyword to VB.net? ("Exists" vs "IsNot Nothing")

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, keyword

`IsNot Nothing` is very common, but it's a double negative =o

I'd like to use `Exists` instead.  Is there someway I can add a keyword to my VB vocab?

For now, I wrote an extension that adds `_Exists()` as a property to each object.  I use this frequently, but I'd still prefer an actual keyword.

```
<HideModuleName()>
Public Module CustomExtensions

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns <c>True</c> if [object] is not <c>Nothing</c>; otherwise <c>False</c>.
    ''' </summary>
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function _Exists(obj As Object) As Boolean
        Return obj IsNot Nothing
    End Function

End Module
```

I use Visual Studio 2010 exclusively, so if I could trick VS into converting my custom phraseology into the standard syntax, that'd work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a nice idea to use an extension method instead of the double negative IsNot Nothing. I'm just wondering: why the underscore? Also, maybe HasValue would be a nicer name; it's the name that Microsoft uses for the method that checks whether a Nullable object has a value.

Comment: Yeah I debated about that, but I ended up using the underscore because I like the visual distinction between `Exists` and the actual object being tested — particularly in cases where the object already contained a series of dots (e.g., a property of a property of an object). I actually have another extension called `HasValue` that I use for strings, which is equal to `Not String.IsNullOrEmpty`.  Good point about Microsoft's built-in method though, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: My 2-cents: don't change the language.  Language is a mode of communication, and you can't communicate if you make your own dialect no one else knows about.  What if you received code with the `Reset` keyword?  What does it mean?  What does it do?  How would you add it to Visual Studio?

Comment: If I saw that code, I'd mouseover `Reset` to see what it does.  If I liked it, I'd start using it myself.  That's how language works in the real world: new words enter our vocabulary all the time; there's no governing body to dictate which words are permissible and which aren't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer isn’t very helpful but here goes: currently, **you cannot do this**.

Future versions of VS (particularly when they release their compiler service internals and make them extensible) could allow it – although I actually doubt that they will allow new keywords to be added, as this isn’t in the interest of a compiler vendor who wants to ensure an ecosystem of compatible code.

Comment: hm, that's pretty surprising given all that VS mods *can* do. Ah well.  Have they actually announced that they'll be releasing those compiler details at some point?

Comment: @J.Steve I’m not sure that there’s an official announcement but some information has been “leaked” by developers, e.g. [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/12/16/hiring-for-roslyn.aspx).